Understanding triggers in Azure SQL database
I have set up a trigger on a table in an Azure SQL database. This trigger is configured to fire on INSERT operations, and it triggers a stored procedure whenever an insert occurs.
I would like to understand the behavior when inserting multiple rows into the table using a single INSERT statement, like in the example below:
INSERT INTO table
SELECT 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 3, 4
UNION
SELECT 4, 5;

In this case, will the trigger (and subsequently the stored procedure) execute only once for the entire INSERT statement, or will it execute three times, once for each row inserted?

Try it, put a print statement in your trigger and run it from SSMS

Or read the documentation. Is it a regular DML trigger? Or a trigger for functions?

If DML then once, with 0-N rows

It will fire once so you cannot process row by row inside the trigger (and you shouldn't either). The table inserted will be populated with 3 rows, so adapt your code accordingly

Agreed with @siggemannen, In SQL, a row-level trigger fires once for each row that is affected by the triggering statement. However, a statement-level trigger fires only once for each execution of the triggering statement, regardless of the number of rows affected.

When you run an INSERT statement like the one you provided, the trigger will fire once for the entire INSERT operation.
The trigger will see all the rows being inserted as a set and will fire only once


Here my stored procedure contains a print statement which will be executed by the trigger after row insertion. After executing your query, it printed inserted only once, which means it fired only once.
